# Magento 1.9.x UTP Payment Integration - document.onreadystatechange issue

Tags: javascript, php, magento

Good Morning all, firstly I must confirm this first. I am not a programmer but have basic knowledge of PHP etc from my teenage years. I am a commercial bee farmer that runs an eCommerce Magento website selling live bees & queens. As we are seasonal it is important our website functions correctly.

We recently changed our payment processor to UTP - Universal Transaction Processing whom offered us Magento to seamlessly integrate our payment for Debit / Credit cards. Unfortunately this has not been the case and our customers have been complaining they are unable to make payment.

After weeks of trying to replicate the issue I managed to replicate it consistently in IE 11 (Sorry I deal with people that use this!). It would load a blank page on transfer from my checkout page.

I widdled it down to the following code

`echo "<script>document.onreadystatechange = () => {document.getElementById('redirect').submit();}</script>";`

My understanding is IE11 has dropped support for this document.onreadystatechange

I modified the code to

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('redirect').submit();</script>";
```

Now I don't believe this is an ideal solution as some browsers are transferring it too early before its read all the form data resulting in errors when payment page is reached.

Is anyone able to offer a solution to this? We are loosing so much custom, it is extremely important to us (being seasonal). Its our only opportunity to make money to survive through winter. This should be UTP's obligiation to fix but they are claiming there is NO issue yet I was able to replicate it multiple times on different platforms, I even set up a FRESH Magento install to prove it to them and they still deny any issue! I am going to and from a company denying there is anything wrong.

Would really appreciate some help in this mmater, here is the full code for this section.

```
    public function redirectPayment() {
    $this->log('Redirecting user for payment');
    // Add hosted parameters to the generic order information
    $session = $this->session->getData();
    $req = array_merge(
        $session[self::_MODULE]['req'],
        array(
            'redirectURL' => $this->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl(),
            'callbackURL' => $this->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl(),
            'formResponsive' => $this->responsive
        )
    );

    // Comment session data
    $this->log($this->commentSessionData());

    $req['signature'] = $this->createSignature($req, $this->secret);

    // Always clear to prevent redirects after
    $this->clearData();

    echo "<form id='redirect' action='" . self::HOSTED_URL . "' method='POST'>";
    // Get session stored keys for a hosted request
    foreach ($req as $key => $value) {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='$key' value='$value'/>";
    }
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<script>document.onreadystatechange = () => {document.getElementById('redirect').submit();}</script>";
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code to -  'echo "<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    {document.getElementById('redirect').submit();}
});</script>";' and it appears to work?

Comment: I do believe this more of an issue regarding the used [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which have been introduced in ES6 and are not supported by IE. [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange) is actually supported by IE. So your attempt above should work fine.